# Need to create dfs.domain.socket.path manually in Hadoop-2.0.0 to use Impala?

Tags: linux, hadoop, hadoop2, impala

I am following the instructions to configure hadoop-2.0.0 cluster for installing Impala. In hdfs-site.xml, I add two properties "dfs.client.read.shortcircuit" and "dfs.domain.socket.path" (/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/dn_socket).

But when I start the Hadoop cluster by start-dfs.sh, it fails to start datanodes. The log in datanode says that "failed to stat a path component: '/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs'". Then I create /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs manually, and start Hadoop cluster again. It fails again and log says that it's the permission problem about that directory. OK, fine. I change the owner of hadoop-hdfs from root to ubuntu (ubuntu is the machine username). Now it finally works normally.

I am just confused. Am I doing in the right way? Do we really need to create /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs by ourselves and change the permission or the owner of that directory? Or I missed some configuration setting?

Comment: Are you doing this command line or using or using Cloudera Manager? What version?

Comment: I did it by command line and never tried Cloudera Manager before. You mean that Cloudera Manager will handle those configuration automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into similar problems using Cloudera Manager. It was an issue of trying to run in 'single-user mode' instead of using root. I think you are doing something similar with user `ubuntu`. Is this a clean install or are you upgrading / did you have a failed install last time?

I'm guessing you sudo-ed somewhere you should have run something as 'ubuntu'.

If you can make it work by manually setting permissions, go for it.  I have a feeling there are lots of other files owned by `root` that should be owned by`ubuntu` lurking about in your system.

Anecdotally, if there is no critical data in the server, I have found it is easier to **very thoroughly** remove any and all files from the old install and then reinstall fresh.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue with starting the datanodes. Then, I came across this link https://github.com/cloudera/Impala/wiki/Build-prerequisites, where it states that we need to create the `/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs` manually and set the appropriate permissions. This has also fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make certain directory `/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/`present is OK.